# Are other birds able to do what owls do as far as mail delivery?

Tags: harry-potter

Usually, Muggles associate pigeons with mail delivery.

Most mentions I recall in Potter wizarding world use owls for this.

Is there something **special** about owls in Potterverse that they have monopoly on this **that excludes other birds**? Or do wizards use other birds as well, and owls are merely a convention/habit?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes.**

There’s at least one canonical mention of this, near the beginning of *Goblet of Fire*:

> Harry had received two letters from Sirius since he had been back at Privet Drive. Both had been delivered, not by owls (as was usual with wizards), but **by large, brightly colored tropical birds**.